# Siunitx: Suppressing decimal alignment for an integer row in a table

Tags: siunitx

How can I align the figures in the column of the following MWE?

The figure in the `N` row is always an integer, so I don't want that to be aligned on the decimal place like the coefficients above: it's too far to the right. Is there any alternative to placing the `N` figures in curly brackets so `siunitx` will disregard them?

Also, the minus sign is much longer than usual without `siunitx`. Is there an option I can specify so that the minus sign is the 'normal' length?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}%Need for STATA tables
\def\tmp{
\parbox{\linewidth-1ex}{
\footnotesize
\lipsum[3-4]
\vspace{1ex}
}
}%Need for STATA tables


\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
@{}l
S[table-format = 3.3,detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-pre    = false,
                table-align-text-post    = false,
        round-precision         = 3,
        table-space-text-pre    = (,
]
}
\toprule

text               &       0.900\sym{***}\\
                    &     (-35.22)        \\

N                   &         512        \\
\bottomrule

\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the point about the minus sign? I suspect you are used to using a hyphen for a minus, but in proper typography the two are distinct (compare for example `-1` and `$-1$` when typeset: the latter is correct).

Answer (score 1):

As per your question regarding `-`:

It appears that `siunitx` uses (for pdflatex, or when fontspec is not loaded) a minus coming from the font in TS1 (text companion) encoding. I am not familiar enough with `siunitx` to tell if there is an option to change that. Hence the method in the proposed code: it replaces the minus sign chosen by `siunitx` by an arbitrary one to yoru liking. For example `\textendash`.

> [image: siunitx minus as textendash]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}%Need for STATA tables
\def\tmp{
\parbox{\linewidth-1ex}{
\footnotesize
\lipsum[3-4]
\vspace{1ex}
}
}%Need for STATA tables


% AWFUL RADICAL HACK WHICH HAS BEEN MUCH FROWNED UPON

%\catcode`_11
%\protected\def \c__siunitx_minus_tl {-}
%\catcode`_ 8 

% RADICAL HACK WHICH MAY STILL BE  MUCH FROWNED UPON

\catcode`_11
\protected\def \c__siunitx_minus_tl {\textendash}
\catcode`_ 8 

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                  @{}l
      S[table-format            = 3.3,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-pre    = false,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        round-precision         = 3,
        table-space-text-pre    = (, 
        detect-mode, 
        ]
}
\toprule
text                &       0.900\sym{***}\\
                    &     (-35.22)        \\
N                   &         {512}      \\
\bottomrule
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

A nice look with the hyphen:

> [image: siunitx minus]

Comment: Your hack is out-and-out wrong: that's not a minus sign, it's a hyphen!

Comment: @JosephWright I deduced that `\ensuremath{-}` would give a too long minus sign in the eyes of the OP, but he/she can always do that rather than my nice hyphen `-`. Or something like `\rule[\fontdimen22\textfont2]{.333em}{.4pt}\hspace{1pt}` to be customized as wished.

Comment: or `\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax`

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this does not work anymore in TL2016